# Snowflake: How to find all errors records while loading parquet data files from aws s3 to snowflake tables

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

```
copy into db.schema.ZDATA_4 
from @stage/load/zdata_4/
file_format=(TYPE=parquet )
ON_ERROR=CONTINUE
Force=TRUE 
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = 
CASE_INSENSITIVE 
validation_mode 
=return_all_errors;
```

While running above load command getting below error message:

*MATCH_BY_COLUMN NAME cannot be used with the VALIDATION.MODE because
VALIDATION_MODE does not support COPY with transform*

In Snowflake, can we load parquet files without match_by_column_name when in validation mode?

Comment: So what happened when you tried it?

Comment: got error message : MATCH_BY_COLUMN NAME cannot be used with the VALIDATION.MODE because VALIDATION_MODE does not support COPY with transform

Comment: I meant what happened when you tried the approach you are asking about: “load parquet files without match_by_column_name when in validation mode”

Answer (score 0):

After loading the parquet data files to Snowflake tables, you will get errors_seen. SQL minus query can be used to find out the records which are not loaded.

```
select col1 || col2 || col3 
from @stage_path
minus
select col1 || col2 || col3
trgt_table
```

Here you wont be able to find the error message or line no.